# diff directories a and b. show only files in b, not in a

Tags: unix, diff

the title sumarises my question. given directories a and b, i want to be able to generate a list of files that are in b but not in a.

a normal diff does this, but it also shows files in a not in b:

```
$ diff -u /mnt/Media/a ~/b    
Only in /mnt/Media/a: abab
Only in /home/conor/b: blah
```

i would also like diff to list filenames only - none of the "Only in .." stuff

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Try this

pick-up one of these :

```
$ LANG=C diff -qr a b | awk -F"Only in b: " '/^Only in b:/{print $2}'
```

or

```
$ LANG=C diff -qr a b | grep -oP "^Only in b: \K.*"
```

or

```
$ LANG=C diff -qr a b | grep '^Only in b:' | cut -d: -f2-
```

### Note

```
LANG=C
```

is only there to avoid displaying in any locale language but in English.

### Doc

See [`man diff`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff)

Comment: hi, that's not working for me. using just "LANG=C diff -aqr a b" it's listing differences between both directories.. the -a option is for comparing as text? i don't want to do that as the files i'm comparing are not text

Comment: Yes, this is for text. Removed `-a` switch. If it still "doesn't work", tell us what's exactly wrong.

Comment: well, it's listing files in a that aren't in b and files in b that aren't in a. as per the title, i only want to list the later - files in b that aren't in a

Comment: Read more carefully my answer

Comment: ah ok, apologies, was testing with the first half of the command. working now using your full answer. thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `uniq` command is more useful than you might imagine.  Consider two directories `dirA` and `dirB`:

```
% ls -R dirA dirB
dirA:
s1/ s2/

dirA/s1:
f2

dirA/s2:
f1  f2

dirB:
s1/ s2/

dirB/s1:
f1  f2

dirB/s2:
f1
%
```

File `s1/f1` is missing from `dirA`, and file `s2/f2` is missing from `dirB`.

Create lists of the contents of the two directories:

```
% (cd dirA; find . -type f >../listA)
% (cd dirB; find . -type f >../listB)
```

Now find the lines which are present *only* in `listB`:

```
% cat listA listA listB | sort | uniq -u 
./s1/f1
%
```

Ta-dah!

Answer (score 4):

Typically when I have to do this, I go low-tech:

```
cd ~/a
find . -type f | sort > ~/fooa
cd ~/b
find . -type f | sort > ~/foob
vimdiff ~/fooa ~/foob
```

It lets me refine the results.  "Oh, whoops, I wanted to exclude .svn directories from ~/a", so rerun the ~/fooa file without .svn directories and then rediff.